# Aggregator transformation in Informatica

Tags: informatica

Is it compulsory to select group-by while performing count operation in the aggregator transformation in Informatica

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: No, you need mention group by , aggregator will just return the last row .. question is what are u trying to achieve by counting without giving a group by option.

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform a count, you have to specify atleast one column in group by to AGGREGATOR transformation to let it know that it has to perform grouping on that column.

Even if you don't provide GROUP BY also, the mapping will not fail, but you won't get the expected result.

Comment: The answer is no. Now hopefully they'll ask you to explain why not (in the interview / assignment this is most likely for) but you don't seem that interested in figuring out that part of the story

Answer (score 0):

While using Aggregator transformation, you need to check group by as the result returns each row by performing aggregation one by one and the passes to the pipeline. If no group by is checked, the last row will be processed and it will return only single row (last row) as it has no command to aggregate data. In order to perform count with respect to specific column, it is manditory to check group  by for required columns.

If you hesitate to group by, you can use expression transformation and use count function to perform aggregation for required column without grouping.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

It's not mandatory to select atleast one port as group by. Hiwever, if you don't choose any group by port - Infa will return only last row.

Hope this helps